# How do i omit existing record django modelformset?

Tags: django, django-models

I am attempting to duplicate a form and have it show just two fields using a modelformset. When I go to run the code django returns all the records in my data base and the requested two empty fields. How do I omit the existing records and only return an empty form every time.

#views

```
def create_player_view(request):
    """"
        allows users to name to 
        players competing vs one another
    """
    PlayersFormSet = modelformset_factory(Players, fields=["playerName",], extra=2, form=PlayerForm)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form  = PlayersFormSet(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            message = ""
           
            form.save()
        else:
            message = "Form could not be completed"

        return render(request, "create_player.html", {"message":message})

    else:
        return render(request, "create_player.html", 
            {'form': PlayersFormSet()})
```

#model

```
class Players(models.Model):
    playerName = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was applying queryset filtering in the wrong place.
I was able to omit the unwanted lines following the docs

[django docs ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)

```
def create_player_view(request):
    """"
        allows users to name to 
        players competing vs one another
    """
    PlayersFormSet = modelformset_factory(Players, fields=["playerName",], extra=2, form=PlayerForm)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form  = PlayersFormSet(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            message = ""
           
            form.save()
        else:
            message = "Form could not be completed"

        return render(request, "create_player.html", {"message":message})


#####SOLUTION BELOW filter as the form is rendered######
   else:
        ***return render(request, "create_player.html", 
            {'form': PlayersFormSet(queryset=Players.objects.none())})***
```